# Kashering a Hard to Clean Pot

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, kashering-kosherization, cleaning

Is it possible to kasher a pot that has areas that are hard to clean, for example the rim? Is there anything one can do to these areas if they can't be completely cleaned out that will allow the pot to be kashered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Shulchan Aruch HaRav](http://www.chabadlibrary.org/books/adhaz/sh/sh3/1/451/19) writes:

> סכין או אחד משאר כלים הצריכין הגעלה שיש בו גומא או סדק או נקב שאינו יכול לחטט בתוכן לנקרן ולנקותן היטיב אין הגעלה מועלת להם אם הן במקום שמשתמשין בו בקבע דהיינו מצד הפנימי של הכלי לפי שיש לחוש שמא יש שם משהו ממשות החמץ בעין ואין הגעלה מועלת למה שהוא בעין לפיכך צריך להניח גחלים בוערות על הסדק והגומא וישהה אותם שם עד שאם יגע אדם כנגדן בצד החיצון של הכלי יהיה היד סולדת בו שאז בודאי נשרף כל ממשות איסור שבתוך הסדק או הגומא והעולם נהגו להחמיר להשהות שם כל כך את הגחלים עד שיהיה קש או חוט נשרף בצד החיצון ואחר כך מגעילן ואם לא עשה כן קודם ההגעלה יעשה כן אחר ההגעלה

One cannot do Hagala on a knife or any other vessel needing Hagala that has a hole or a crack that's not cleanable, as we're concerned that it may be pieces of visible Chometz there, and Hagala doesn't remove visible chometz. Therefore, one has to place burning coals on the crack until the knife gets hot enough that the other side of it will be Yad Soledes bo, as the chametz will definitely be burned up.

The world, however, is accustomed to put the coals long enough that straw touching the other side of the knife will start burning.

Then one does regular Hagalah.

Comment: Why couldn't you just ensure there is 60x the volume of the crumb in the Hagalah?

Comment: @DoubleAA That would ensure that the water or (possibly, see Issur Davuk) knife stay kosher during Hagalah. Once it comes out the crumb can make the pot Treif the next use (or possibly that same use if the pot is hot)

Comment: That's only a concern for Chametz which is not batel at all. For regular issurim this should be like a pot which we know only absorbed a very small amount and which is always used for large amounts (99:7, cf 98:5).